# butterknife upgrading from 7.0.1 to 8.8.1 in AS 3.0 android

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, butterknife

**My previous config**

AS =  2.3

gradle  = 2.3.3

distributionUrl = https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Views referenced via @Bind(R.id.tvName)

**My current config**

AS =  3.0.1

gradle  = 3.0.1

distributionUrl = https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Now I have to refer views as @BindView(R.id.tvName)

**What I did**

I replaced every occurance of @Bind with @BindView by ctrl+shft+R

**What happened**

When I run the project I get **cannot find symbol class BindView**

**Gradle**

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'

annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

[image]

Comment: did you add the annotionProcessor?

Comment: yes I did......

Comment: why are you using the 9.0.0 snapshot when you're saying you're using 8.8.1

Comment: sorry also tried with 9.0.0  .  Now post edited to 8.8.1

Comment: Did you import `BindView`?

Comment: offcourse I did . When I run project every @BindView turns to red ( showing error ) for a while and then to nornal . Apart from compile & annotation process is anything I have to include ?

Comment: Have you tried `invalidate caches`?

Comment: @Epic doing now .lets see

Comment: @Epic  : tried didn't worked

Comment: Then you just didn't do `Ctrl+Shift+R` on the `import` statements for the `import butterknife.Bind;` to `import butterknife.BindView`.

Comment: I did .........